# ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

can anyone help, i am beginner in python. i downloaded a code from github (https://github.com/juanmed/quadrotor_sim/blob/master/3D_Quadrotor/3D_control.py) and i am trying to run this code, but i am getting below error. which i am not able to debug.

Error

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-T T] [--time_step TIME_STEP]
                             [-w WAYPOINTS [WAYPOINTS ...]] [--seed SEED]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\Mmqua\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-8c388a04-950e-45d6-aa84-beb35baf096a.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2


C:\Users\Mmqua\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3275: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbTvU.jpg)